# Permission denied(public key) in ssh while installing iotivity

Tags: system

When I run `ssh gerrit.iotivity.org`, I get `permission denied(public key)` error.

Before this, I run the following command:

```
ProxyCommand nc -X5 -x <proxy-address>:<port> %h %p
```

with my proxy address and port.

My ssh config file is as follows:

```
Host iotivity gerrit.iotivity.org 
Hostname gerrit.iotivity.org 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
User [Teju]
Port 29418
```

Please help.

Comment: use the private key file (`id_rsa` without the `.pub`) for the identity file and try again

Answer (score 1):

When generating the keys use a name `id_rsa` without any extension. And use the following content in the config file:

```
Host iotivity gerrit.iotivity.org 
Hostname gerrit.iotivity.org 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
User Teju
Port 29418
```